# Which way shall I use foreign key in Django

Tags: python, sql, django, model

I have two models, Employee and Withdraw. Which way shall I do the referencing?
Like this, as Employee have 0-many withdraws,

```
class Withdraw(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    withdraw = models.ForeignKey(Withdraw, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

OR

```
class Withdraw(models.Model):
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What are the pros/cons? Which would you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one, as Withdraw needs an employee whereas Employee does not need a withdraw.

Comment: This is correct, but the more important reason is that each withdrawal only comes from one employee, but each employee can presumably make multiple withdrawals.